# Install-SitecoreConfiguration : One or more errors returned from Solr request

Tags: solr, installation, habitat

I have cloned following Habitat project on my local environment:

https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/

And here is the link stating that solr 7.2.1 is supported

https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/docs/01-Getting-Started.md

I have also changed xconnect-solr and sitecore-solr in the assets folder(here is the screenshot of same with highlighted changes).
[image]

**Error: Here is the issue which I am seeing in logs now, could anyone confirm why this issue is there and if this is related to solr versioning or not.**
[image]
[image]

And the screenshot of response from solr url mentioned in error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see on your screenshot you try to install **Sitecore 9.0** with **Solr 7.2.1**. It is not supported *(Sitecore 9.0 only supports Solr 6.6.1-6.6.3)*. 
[image]

See solr compatibility table here https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

You need **Sitecore 9.1.0**:

[image]